# Secure resource on the website so only stakeholders and not the public can read it

Tags: security, web

right now I am working a system which shall only be available to business stakeholders, so customers, employees, delivery and so on. They shall get a specific information via a website, but this information should not be available to the public. We logically don't offer a system which is accessible to stakeholders only, since they have to get this information anonymously (it changes over time) and we could easily identify them by using a specific system.

What I need right now are concepts which may provide anonymity and still prevents parts of the public from the resource.

Comment: While an interesting question, this is very, very broad and vague. It would be better that you go away and research what mechanism suits you best (from HTTPAuth to a 3rd party interface such as PHP to Apache `.htaccess` to 2FA or Public/Private Key Encryption, etc. etc.) and then come back to us when you have a specific mechanism and a specific issue with that mechanism

Answer (score 0):

Password protect it and give them the password. You don't need to know who they are to do that. Alternately, give them random accounts if you want them to be separate and not share a single password. But what you've described is most easily implemented with a single password. It just means you can't revoke access.

You can also have all of your stakeholders provide you an anonymous public key. You encrypt the password against all of the keys, and post it publicly. That way you can change the password and re-post it, without knowing who downloads it. But this will put more complexity on your users, who will need to maintain a private key. You likely will need to provide them software to facilitate this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We do think that a simple password would be enough, due to the fact, that it has to be changed, and again communicated with all stakeholders, if it gets compromised. We do not have a platform to share it with all stakeholders besides sending it via mail, which will again lead to the original problem :/

Comment: What mechanism do you use to determine that they are "stakeholders" in the first place?

Comment: They will send us confidential information and we will validate that the information is correct and can only be known by our stakeholders. We will give them anonymous accounts and answer them so we can guarantee, that only the right people are giving information to us anonymously.

But for now we decided, that our fact checking is enough protection by itself. We will accept all accesses and validate their requests instead of blocking them beforehand.